# Trying to find a stray '{' and/or '}' curly bracket

Tags: javascript, cytoscape.js, cytoscape-web

I get 2 errors testing through my code, and it was working before I turned my function to an async and added the new Promise to the loop.

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: missing } after property list
note: { opened at line 624, column 26
```

What's confusing is that it says it's on line 624 which doesn't make sense because emy code is only about 200 lines. (I'm assuming it counts each loop as a line maybe?)

And clicking on the links to the error line send me to these two lines **specifically**:

```
data: {
       id: await checkID(node_point)
```

I've put my code through beautifiers, through bracket counters, and I tried reading the documentation of [Cytoscape](https://js.cytoscape.org/#cy.add) to see if the formatting was correct for the function (cy.add).

I'm convinced its something else that's causing the issue.

Here is the rest of the code for reference:

```
async function draw() {

    api = await apiPromise;
    nodes = await api.query.proxy.proxies.entries();
    proxy_actions = await api.query.proxy.announcements.entries();

    addNodePromises = [];
    for (node in nodes) {

        addNodePromise = new Promise(() => {

            node_point = nodes[node][0].toHuman()[0]; //nodes in graph
            edges = nodes[node][1][0].toHuman(); //node edges/graph connections

            //Adding node points    
            cy.add([{
                group: "nodes",
                data: {
                    id: await checkID(node_point)
                },
                position: {
                    x: 0,
                    y: 0
                }
            }, ]);

            //And here the deleates
            for (proxy of edges) {
                cy.add([{
                    group: "nodes",
                    data: {
                        id: await checkID(proxy.delegate)
                    },
                    position: {
                        x: 0,
                        y: 0
                    }
                }, ]);
            }

            //Adding edges
            var i = 0;
            for (proxy of edges) {
                cy.add([{
                    group: "edges",
                    data: {
                        id: proxy.proxyType + i + "\n",
                        source: await checkID(node_point),
                        target: await checkID(proxy.delegate)
                    }
                }, ]);
                i++;
            }

        }); //end promise
        addNodePromises.append(addNodePromise);

    } //end for loop
    await Promises.all(addNodePromises);
    lay();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main thing I see is an `await` that's not in an `async` function:

```
        addNodePromise = new Promise(() => {
        // ...
                        id: await checkID(proxy.delegate)
        // ...
        }); //end promise
```

Your `new Promise` also doesn't have a `resolve`/`reject` even defined as arguments. Which means it would never resolve.

The easiest way to fix is probably to declare this way instead of using `new Promise` syntax:

```
        addNodePromise = async () => {
        // ...
        }; //end promise

        // invoke async function; note change here:
        addNodePromises.append(addNodePromise());
```

Edit: if you're not already using a good JavaScript linter, like eslint, I'd recommed it. It will help you find things like this.

Comment: Yes! Thank you that did solve the issue, I don't understand why it was telling me I was missing a curly bracket. In either case, it resolved my issue. 
In regards to the resolve/reject definition, won't Promise.all() handle the resolution of the promise?

Comment: Nope: `Promise.all` creates a new promise, which resolves once all promises in the array have resolved. But the promises in the array have to resolve on their own. RE the cryptic error: my guess would be your dev environment was confused by the `await` syntax outside of an `async` function, and stopped parsing corretly at that point, which made it not see the closing curly brace. That's a guess. Eslint gave a much more understandable error when I checked your code with it.